# How to Set A Custom Load order For My User display Table based on Ranks

Tags: php, sql

So I am Currently Building a new CMS for my Community and have run into a minor issue. I want to be able to List Ranks from Highest in the Chain of Command to lowest, but I cannot work out how to do this using my string based ranks.

```
    <?php
    include "dbh.php";
    include "header.php";
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_leo";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $rank = $row["rank"];
    $department = $row["department"];



    ?>
    <div class="login-page">
    </div>
    <div class='form'>
    <?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users_leo";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<table>
     <tr>
        <th>In-Game Name</th>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Department</th>
        <th>Profile</th>
     </tr>";
      while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>"; echo $row['username']; echo"</td>";
        echo "<td>"; echo $row['username']; echo"</td>";
        echo "<td>"; echo $row['department'];  echo"</td>";
        echo '<td><a class="viewProfile" href="profile.php?id=' . $row['id']. '"><button>View Profile</button></a></td>';
        echo "</tr>";

    }
}
    ?>

  </div>
</div>
  </body>
```

As You can see int the below code, the Ranks are stored as Strings

```
 echo "<select name='rank'>
<option value='Corrections Officer'>Corrections Officer</option>
<option value='Senior Corrections Officer'>Senior Corrections Officer</option>
<option value='DOC Corporal'>DOC Corporal</option>
<option value='DOC Sergeant'>DOC Sergeant</option>
<option value='DOC Lieutenant'>DOC Lieutenant</option>
<option value='DOC Head Lieutenant'>DOC Head Lieutenant</option>
<option value='DOC Command'>DOC Command</option>
<option value='Trooper 3rd class'>Trooper 3rd Class</option>
<option value='Trooper 2nd class'>Trooper 2nd Class</option>
<option value='Trooper 1st class'>Trooper 1st Class</option>
<option value='Lance Corporal'>Lance Corporal</option>
<option value='State Corporal'>State Corporal</option>
<option value='State Sergeant'>State Sergeant</option>
<option value='First Sergeant'>First Sergeant</option>
<option value='2nd Lieutenant'>2nd Lieutenant</option>
<option value='1st Lieutenant'>1st Lieutenant</option>
<option value='State Command'>State Command</option>
<option value='Officer'>Officer</option>
<option value='Senior Officer'>Senior Officer</option>
<option value='Police corporal'>Police Corporal</option>
<option value='Police Sergeant'>Police Sergeant</option>
<option value='Staff Sergeant'>Staff Sergeant</option>
<option value='Police Lieutenant'>Police Lieutenant</option>
<option value='Police Head Lieutenant'>Police Head Lieutenant</option>
<option value='PD Command'>PD Command</option>
<option value='Overseer'>Overseer</option>
    </select>
```

I have tried and tried but cannot find a solution P.S. I am willing to change all the ranks to numbers if someone can then explain how to set it so they are displayed as the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If you want to select String in highest to lowest order than here is the code ASC[ascending to Descending] and DESC[descending to Ascending]**

```
SELECT * FROM users_leo ORDER BY column_name ASC [or] DESC;
```